# How to resolve issue with handling csrf with multiple tabs in express/nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, csrf, csrf-protection

I built CSRF protection in my nodejs/express application with the following config:

```
var app = express(),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    session = require('express-session'),
    csrf = require('csurf');

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    , saveUninitialized: true
    , resave: true
    , store: new MongoStore()
}));

app.use(flash());
```

And with the following login form:

```
<form action="/process" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{csrfToken}}">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The problem arives when user opens two browser tabs and end of the story is getting `EBADCSRFTOKEN` error at [this line](https://github.com/expressjs/csurf/blob/master/index.js#L111):

Let's see the following case:

1. User opens the form above in two separate tabs.
2. In first tab he do logout and signin again.
3. Then switches to second tab, click submit and get `EBADCSRFTOKEN` error.

I need to point that I destroy my session in `logout` route:

```
app.route('/auth/signout')
    .get(function (req, res, next) {

        return req.session.destroy(function (err) {
            if (err) return next(err);

            return res.redirect('/');
        });
    });
```

Because that fact that I destroy the session I destroy the secret also key that stored there. So this destroing leads to invalid token on second tab and `EBADCSRFTOKEN` error.

I need to resolve this case somehow. What you do in this case? Show popup to reload the page or reload page automatically?

Comment: Why are you destroying the session on a `GET`? Create a `POST` handler  for logout and destroy the session when the users posts the form, not when he casually visits `/auth/signout`.

Comment: Yes I can? but this don't resovle my initial prolem

Comment: And that's why it's a comment not an answer. :D

Comment: ok thanks but I don't see resons to use POST instead GET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The csrf token should be set and retrieved from cookie before form submission. Suppose, you open tabA with csrf `C1`. Once you open tab2, the csrf changes to `C2`. But, if this is set in the cookies, fetching csrf from cookies in tabA will give `C2` as csrf token.

Same thing can be concluded with session->logout->new_session. Save and fetch everything from the cookie. Since you logged in after a logout in tab2, tab1 will have cookies of tab2 and also the csrf token.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what about secutiry? Has storing token in cooke worse than storing in session from the security reasons?

Comment: No, it is a two way storage. A copy of cookie and associated csrf token is stored in stored in server as well. So the combination is always verified when sent by the client. Hence it is safe !

Comment: Ok, but I don't agree with your phrase: `Suppose, you open tabA with csrf C1. Once you open tab2, the csrf changes to C2`. In csurf module this is not a problem because `C2` still also valid because of generating token with secret https://github.com/pillarjs/csrf/blob/master/index.js#L105